# Email validation in mvc view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I know we can add Regular Expression in Model class in MVC but I was wondering is there any way to add that in MVC view.

```
   <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "E mail", @required = "Required", @type = "email" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                        </div>
```

By using @type="email" I must have to put @ in the textbox e.g abc@abc but it allows me to submit the form without entering .com i.e abc@abc.com, so how can I force it to ask a user to enter "." in email to submit a form.
Thanks

Comment: Why not create a view model ( not your entity model) and apply data annotation on the email property on that ? Regex ?

Comment: Add the `[EmailAddress]` attribute to your property and remove the `@required = "Required", @type = "email"` attributes (they are HTML5 validation only and are ignored if your using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` and in any case will not give your server side validation which is the most important)